# Delete the first instance of an object in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects like this:

```
[ 
  {id: 0, title: 'A'},  
  {id: 2, title: 'C'},  
  {id: 1, title: 'B'}, 
  {id: 0, title: 'A'},  
]
```

Object to remove from array:

```
{id: 0, title: 'A'}
```

How can I delete the first instance of the object from an array of objects to produce the following output:

```
[ 
  {id: 2, title: 'C'},  
  {id: 1, title: 'B'}, 
  {id: 0, title: 'A'},  
]
```

Maybe using filter or map?

Comment: You want to delete the first instance or all instances?

Comment: This thread might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/5767357/14948175

Comment: your example isn't clear at all. `{id: 0, title: 'A'}` still exist twice in the output. Also, why did `{id: 0, title: 'C'}` became `{id: 2, title: 'C'}`?

Comment: yep, `id` should be unique.

Comment: maybe the object to be deleted is `{id: 0, title: 'C'}`?

Answer (score 4):

If you only want to remove the first instance of the object you can do the following with [findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) and [splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

```
const obj = { id: 0, title: "A" };
const index = arr.findIndex((i) => i.id === obj.id && i.title === obj.title);
arr.splice(index, 1);
```

It would be quickest to check for the matching object by using the object properties like I used above. If you have a large object with lots of properties and it might be easier to use something like lodash's [isEqual](https://lodash.com/docs/#isEqual) utility. `arr.findIndex(i => isEqual(i, obj))`

Comment: your solution seem to be the correct solution based on the description - eventhough OP's example makes no sense

Comment: In case you want to keep the original array `arr` then simply precede the above action with a shallow copy assignment like `b=[...arr];b.splice(b.findIndex(o=>o.title=="A"&&o.id==0),1)`.

Comment: Thanks. It's is solution for my problem. 

P.S Sorry guys if my question makes some problems for all of you.

Answer (score 3):

Try to do this by id.

```js
const collection = [{ id: 0, title: 'A' }, { id: 2, title: 'C' }, { id: 1, title: 'B' }, { id: 0, title: 'A' }, { id: 2, title: 'C' }, { id: 0, title: 'C' }];

const updatedCollection = collection.filter(({ id }) => id !== 0);

console.log(updatedCollection);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var arr = [1,2,3,5,7,5,9,11,13,5,9,0];
    
    for( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){ 
                                   
        if ( arr[i] === 5) 
        { 
            arr.splice(i, 1); 
            i--; 
        }
    }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr=[ {id: 0, title: 'A'},  {id: 2, title: 'C'},  {id: 1, title: 'B'}, {id: 0, title: 'A'},  {id: 2, title: 'C'} ]
const arrupdate = arr.filter(({ id }) => id !== 1);
console.log(arrupdate);
```